# How to get the current spec name in Jasmine2

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine2.0

I am trying to get the current spec name in Jasmine2 using

1. `spec.getFullName()` - which is valid in Jasmine1 but not Jasmine2
2. `spec.description`:

   ```
   var spec = it ('spec name' ,function () {
       console.log(spec.description);
   });
   ```

But neither works. 
Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/611.

Comment: You second sample seems to be working ([see plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LabF91p4i3XCBFSLuL2q?p=preview))

Comment: But I got this error:
Failed: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined